# Is there an easy way to share the power and I2C GPIO pins between multiple sensors without soldering?

Tags: i2c, sensor

I'm trying to connect multiple sensors to the Power and I2C pins of the GPIO header of a Pi 3B, but I can't find an easy way to do it using the standard plug-in jumper cables that are often used for prototyping.

All I could find was [these splitters](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71eziE429gL._AC_SL1500_.jpg) on Amazon, which would allow me to connect two devices, assuming the pins are the right size (as it happens the pins I need are [next to each other](https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/measuring-rotation-and-acceleration-raspberry-pi/)):

[image: splitter product]

I was hoping for something that could be "stacked", like these banana plug jumpers but obviously smaller:

[image: stacking banana jumpers]

It seems to me that I2C is very convenient for connecting multiple sensors, since they can all share the same pins - but it would be a shame if I can't get this sharing to occur without soldering or introducing a bulky solderless breadboard...

Comment: There are two to eight ways compact, space saving latch lever splitters.  I also DIY Tamiya signal/power one male to multiple female connectors.  For more than 8 connectors, I usually solder proto board 5 connect strip boards for I2C or SPI signal splitters: https://imgur.com/gallery/b9Z8ygK.

Comment: Two more related answers your may find useful. I usually go to Pimoroni for DIY ideas: (1) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104705/how-to-tap-tee-fork-the-rpi-gpio-pins-covered-blocked-by-a-hat-phat-bo
(2) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104307/how-to-physically-wire-two-i2c-sensors-scl-sda-signals-to-a-single-i2c-bus. You may also find in one of my answers about the I2C wiring related, annoying, GROUNDING problem and how to avoid the trouble.

Comment: This is the thing I refer above: PCT-213 222-413 Spring Lever Push Fit Cable 3 wire Wiring Connector Universal Compact Terminal Block
https://www.dhgate.com/product/-100-pieces-lot-wago-222-413-pct-213-type/400202993.html

Comment: @tlfong01 Thanks for the link to the other question. I decided to post my answer there: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/106299/91313

Comment: You are welcome.  Nice to read your answer later.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Use a breadboard like the rest of us. They come in many sizes; the smaller breadboards will take up less space, and you are less likely to damage the Pi.

NOTE to use I²C you **NEED** 3 connections at least and most I²C devices also need a 4th connection for power.

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/79884/8697 but there are hundreds of tutorials.